# Use of overloaded comparison operator> in C++ in conjunction with a getter function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, comparison-operators, return-by-reference

I'm struggling with a problem concerning the overloading of the binary comparison operator >. By design, it is supposed to compare two cards and return either 1 (if the left-hand-side argument is bigger) or 0 (in the opposite case).

Here's a brief description of the problem:

`class Card` includes, among other stuff, the variables `int suit` and `int value` as private data members. I've declared the overloaded operator function as follows:

`int operator>(const Card& lhs, const Card& rhs);`

Because it needs to access private data members of `class Card`, it is declared with the `friend` qualifier in the class declaration.

The function itself is confirmed to work as described. The real problem lies with providing the two arguments by calling a 'getter' function of the following form:

```
 Card &Node::getCardRef() const{
       Card& ref = *c;
       return ref;
 }
```

where the variable `c` is of type `Card *` and points to a valid object of type `Card`. Also, an instance of `class Node` represents a node in a singly-linked list.

Combining the two functions in the following manner causes a segfault (specifically, in gdb terms "In Card &Node::getCardRef(): this = 0x0"):

```
 if (node.getCardRef() > node.getNext()->getCardRef()){   

 /* do wondrous stuff */

  }
```

Also, when isolated, `Card &Node::getCardRef()` seems to produce desired results.

Comment: Doesnt getNext() return NULL?

Comment: The object pointed to by `c` resides on stack or freestore? if it resides on stack,then you are returning a reference to an local variable which results in an Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Normally, one would define `operator>` returning `bool`

Comment: are you sure getNext() return a valid pointer/object/reference

Comment: I realize that, I have just remove my comment. Forgive me it is friday afternoon

Comment: @elmov: to expand on André Puel's idea: if it is possible for `node.getNext()` to return NULL, you need to exit before that happens, e.g.: `if (node.getNext() == NULL) { return; }`

Comment: @Alessandro Teruzzi: No worries `:)`

Comment: @Als: the `Card` object pointed to by c is dynamically allocated.

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi: in this particular case, `getNext()` returns a valid pointer to another `Node`.

Comment: @elmov: Are you sure? The error message `this = 0x0` looks like a NULL pointer to me.

Comment: Another quibble, if you declare `getCardRef()` to be a `const` function it really should return only a `const` reference.

Comment: During further investigation it turns out that, indeed, getNext() returns NULL in the course of a hastily written loop. Cheers everybody! I presumed it must've had to do with my inexperience in operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

> "In Card &Node::getCardRef(): this = 0x0")

```
if (node.getCardRef() > node.getNext()->getCardRef()){
```

`Node::getCardRef` is called twice in that code fragment. The first time as a result of the `.` operator, so we can be reasonably certain<sup>*</sup> that its `this` will be valid.

The other call to `Node::getCardRef` is the result of the `->` operator. It is entirely likely that the left-hand-side of the `->` is 0 (thus, `this` will be 0, also).

It is very likely the case that `node.getNext()` is returning 0. Singly-linked lists usually indicate the end-of-list condition by returning a null pointer.

I guess that you are comparing the final item on your linked list with the null item that doesn't follow it.

---

<sup>*: we can be reasonably certain, but not 100% certain. It is possible that node contains a corrupt reference, or that a previous wild pointer has corrupted our local variables. In my experience, null pointers are much more likely than null references.</sup>

Comment: Okay, I just noticed the entire comment string came to the same conclusion as I did. I'll leave this answer here, as a CW, so I don't get any undeserved credit.